# Line break in a span with defined width?

Tags: css, line-breaks

How can I break a line in a span once the width of the span is reached? I tried max-width, but this did not work, the span is always as long as the text.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, `<span>` elements are 'inline', and will always grow to the size of their content. You need to explicitly declare the `<span>` to be `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: +1 that's correct.. just for the OP consideration - if you need a block element you better use one that's already block (div, p etc.)

Answer (score 15):

```
span { 
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`span` is an **inline** element, meaning, it is wrapped around text (or other inline elements). It is not subject to `width` or `height`.

You want a **block** element, like a `div`, or maybe an **inline-block** element (achieved by setting `display: inline-block` on an element).

Comment: I am using display:none on the span because I am hiding it with Prototype. So setting display:block for example shows it when the page loads, which is not what I want. How can I handle this?